# Add the value of a button press to a string

Tags: javascript

Trying to build a calculator...

Ive got my button presses working however cant quite figure out the best way to "remember" the button press and get a 2nd parameter to calculate.

Could anyone point me in the right direction? pretty new to this, Thanks

```js
var results = document.getElementById("calcResults")
var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName("calcButton")

//Add Event listener to all the buttons 
for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
  buttons[i].addEventListener("click", btnPress)
}

//Display the button press
function btnPress() {
  var x = this.innerHTML;

  //Show the button press
  document.getElementById("calcResults").innerHTML = x;
  console.log(x);
}
```

No Errors just trying to learn :)

Comment: How is anyone supposed to help if you don't even show the HTML, let alone a runnable snippet?

Comment: You'll want to do something with `x`. You'll likely want another variable, like `y = x`, and then calculate based on the sign, then reset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I get you .I think you need to declare a global variable for the result which has a zero as a value, 
then inside your `btnPress` function, you need to assign the previous result plus the button value and then you will get your result ?

```
var results = document.getElementById("calcResults")
var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName("calcButton")
let result = 0
//Add Event listener to all the buttons 
for(var i = 0; i<buttons.length; i++){
buttons[i].addEventListener("click", btnPress)
}
//Display the button press
function btnPress() {

var x = this.innerHTML;
result = result + x 

//Show the button press
document.getElementById("calcResults").innerHTML = result
console.log(x);
}
```